# Being interpreted and dynamic module loading

Tags: python, python-2.7

Python is an interpreted language, and it has built-in support for dynamic module loading.

Does the former make it easier for the latter? Or the two are unrelated?

Some conceptual explanation would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I use Python where I can and C where I must. I can load libraries dynamically on both and I don't see much of a difference. So IMHO no, these are orthogonal concepts.

Lines may blurry because you can load binary modules in Python, and you can embed a dynamic interpreter in C (Python being a little big for this, I prefer Lua or scheme).

Where being dynamic helps is with fast prototyping and introspection, because you can skip compile cycles and the REPL makes much easier to experiment and inspect live code snippets. Python has wonderful introspection features, so you can load an unknown module on the REPL and inspect all classes and functions - in C you probably would have to read some header file to get the data types and function signatures.